# Squarespace Custom Product Post Type

Tags: json, e-commerce, squarespace

I was thinking about creating **different templates for products** (not with different features but with different html organization and css) because the standard "pic on the left and data on the right" is not enough for a well-made user-centered ecommerce.

I tried the **custom post types** but they are blog post and can't access the product data.

in my custom `product.conf` i added my custom post data

```
 "acceptTypes" : ["store_item", "custom-product-item"]
```

but obv. it won't work.

maybe if I could access the store_item could be easier to do this, but i can't find on the repo.

anyone has some suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, although it used to be possible to create custom post type products, that stopped being possible within the last year or so.

If you want to create your own template for products, you need to override the `products.list` and/or `products.item` files with your own. By placing them within your `/collections` folder, it will override the system default ones.

That means you have to write it entirely from scratch. Here are a couple resources that may help (despite being outdated):

- http://www.bcarroll.us/developer-platform-tutorials/2014/10/20/products-pages
- https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/57343/productsitem-for-adirondack-template.html

Having overridden products.item, if you want to have different templates for different products, you can do something like:

```
{.equal? item.urlId "myurlid1"}
  {@|apply products1.block}
{.or equal? item.urlId "myurlid2"}
  {@|apply products2.block}
{.or}
  etc.
```

Comment: Seems like products.list nor products.item are overridable anymore. Tested with local development server, and creating those files made no effect to product listing or item pages.

Comment: @KarriRasinmäki: Those files are indeed still overridable. The local development server will ignore your local `products.list` and `products.item` files. You must commit and push the replacement files to the live server in order to view the changes in the local environment. Also, you may have to append `?nocache=true` to your URL in order to bust the local dev. environment cache and view the updated layouts in the local dev. environment.